# Unison: should I use a remote shell (ssh) or VPN tunnel?

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, ssh-tunnel, unison

We have 2 office locations. Each LAN is connected via a site-to-site OpenVPN tunnel.

- Office1 has an Ubuntu Server; samba file shares; OpenSSH server; Unison File Synchronizer.
- Office2 has a Win Server 2012R2; replicated copies of the same file shares; OpenSSH client; Unison File Synchronizer.

Currently, Office2 Win Task Scheduler runs a Unison file sync every 15 minutes with Office1 via remote shell method, ssh tunnel.

Is there any advantage to using the remote shell method, ssh tunnel? I could easily map the samba shares from Office1 (Ubuntu) onto Office2 (Win Server) and have Unison sync files over the openVPN tunnel instead.

Pros/Cons of using SSH vs. OpenVPN?

We're soon scrapping the Office1 Ubuntu Server OS and replacing it with Win Server 2012R2 OS. So, the openSSH server will be going away. Trying to fig. out if I should go down the road of setting up a new OpenSSH server on the new Win box.

Thanks!